# curveVertex() not drawling in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a script that drawls a curve through 'n' vertexes equally spaced around the center of an ellipse.

The reason I'm not just drawling an ellipse around the center ellipse is because I eventually want to connect a micro-controller to Processing where the data points acquired from the 'n' amount of sensors will vary the height ('y') of each vertex, creating constantly changing, irregular curves around the center ellipse such as this possible curve:

[image]

Essentially, this is supposed to be a data visualizer, but I cannot figure out why this is not working or how to achieve this effect after going through examples and the documentation on https://processing.org/reference/.

---

Here is my code:

```
color WHITE = color(255);
color BLACK = color(0);

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    background(WHITE);
    translate(width/2, height/2); // move origin to center of window

    // center ellipse
    noStroke();
    fill(color(255, 0, 0));
    ellipse(0, 0, 10, 10); // center point, red

    fill(BLACK);
    int n = 10;
    int y = 100;
    float angle = TWO_PI / n;
    beginShape();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rotate(angle);
        curveVertex(0, y);
    }
    endShape();
}
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Fix tag as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix operations like [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) do not transform the single vertices in a shape. The current matrix is applied to the entire shape when it is draw (at  `endShape`). You've to calculate all the vertex coordinates:

Create a [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) of [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html), fill it with points and draw it in a loop:

```java
color WHITE = color(255);
color BLACK = color(0);

ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);

    int n = 10;
    int radius = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        float angle = TWO_PI * (float)i/n;
        points.add(new PVector(cos(angle)*radius, sin(angle)*radius));
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(WHITE);
    translate(width/2, height/2);

    noFill();
    stroke(255, 0, 0);

    beginShape();
    PVector last = points.get(points.size()-1);
    curveVertex(last.x, last.y);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        PVector p = points.get(i);
        curveVertex(p.x, p.y);
    }
    PVector first = points.get(0);
    curveVertex(first.x, first.y);
    endShape();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Is there a specified reason I cannot drawl these coordinates using rotate?

Comment: The vertices which are set between `beginShape` and `endShape` are add to a vertex buffer. The matrix is not designed to be applied to the specific coordinates in the this buffer. After the buffer is created it is drawn. The matrix is applied to every shape which is drawn. Note, a shape can be stored to a [`PShape`](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_beginShape_.html) object and the object can be draw to multiple times to different positions in the scene. The positions are defiend by the current matrix when the shape is drawn.